# Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1 Error when archiving

Tags: objective-c, ios, archive

I'm trying to archive a project to submit it to the iOS App Store, but keep getting this problem.  I have already set yes to the skip install option, re-installed Xcode, rebooted and re-copied my libraries, as well as edited my schemes. I've done my research and tried everything suggested, but still get this error.

Does anybody has a suggestion?

```
chown: /Users/Samuel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Safari-clksdtmdmbdyrefxcltqlpejzefv/ArchiveIntermediates/Branon/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/i386: No such file or directory
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: You might get a better answer on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Check your architectures... for some reason it thinks you're building an i386 something, so there's something in there somewhere that shouldn't be.

Comment: The complete error is slightly too long to put in a comment (700 characters).  It's available on this paste bin: http://pastebin.com/dMkMHSzm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jason Coco - I got a chance to look at this again and you were right.  Architectures!

Sam